# How can I delay the changing of a watched variable that is tied to an <input> field

Tags: angularjs

I set up a watch expression that watches some data that is entered into an input field that is backed up by the $scope.pid

```
  $scope.$watch("pid", function (pid) {
        if (pid == null || pid === "") {
            $scope.pidLower = null;
            $scope.pidUpper = null;
        }
        else if (pid.indexOf("-") > 0) {
            pid = pid.split("-");
            $scope.pidLower = parseInt(pid[0]);
            $scope.pidUpper = parseInt(pid[1]);
        }
        else {
            $scope.pidLower = parseInt(pid);
        }
    });
```

It works good but once the pidLower or pidUpper change then there are more functions that are called and some heavy processing. The result is that I have to wait a short time in between entering numbers into the input field.

Is there a way I can add some kind of timeout to this so that the watch function code does not change anything until the information entered into the input field has not changed for three seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout) service for this. After you've injected this service into your controller you can do the following:

```
var parsePid = function() {...};

$scope.$watch("pid", function (pid) {
   if($scope.timeoutPromise) {
      $timeout.cancel($scope.timeoutPromise);
   }
   $scope.timeoutPromise = $timeout(function() {
      parsePid();
   }, 3000);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to validate your input before further processing. Instead of watching `pid` you can add filter. In filter you can change `$scope.pidLower` and `$scope.pidUpper` based on some condition , which will trigger your further heavy processing. Refer [$filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) for details.